# Fatal error: Class 'Browser' not found : After Updating drupal 6.20 to 6.26

Tags: 6, updating

As i am update my durpal version 6.20 to 6.26 and it gives these error after updating.

```
   1) Fatal error: Class 'Browser' not found in /opt/lampp/htdocs/mydrupal/includes/common.inc(1731) : eval()'d code on line 4

   2) warning: include(Browser.php) [function.include]: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /opt/lampp/htdocs//opt/lampp/htdocs/uls/includes/mydrupal/includes/common.inc(1731) : eval()'d code on line 3.
```

I checked the common.inc file and there is no code for "including browser.php"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message says `eval()'d code on line 4`. You have a PHP block, node or something similar that tries to include a file called `Browser.php`. That is not a file supplied with Drupal core. What you can do... just before line 1731 add something like `if(strpos($code, 'Browser.php')) { file_put_contents('/tmp/log', print_r(debug_backtrace(), TRUE)); exit;}` and then study the log to see where it's called from to figure it out. If it's called from block, the backtrace will contain the module and delta, if it's a node, the nid will be there and so on.

Comment: thanx for reply... one thing more i noticed just now that problem is with my custom theme.. not with garland theme.

Comment: That's probably because it is a block that is only shown in your custom theme. Check your custom blocks that are enabled on that theme. Or disable the PHP filter then you should see it.

Comment: @chx thankx buddy you saved my time.. :D i found the code in view..

Comment: sorry but i dont konw how to do that please tell?

Comment: http://i39.tinypic.com/5evj1e.jpg